# How can i fix this my vanity lights?

Tags: electrical, lighting

There are 6 lights on my vanity three on each side, you can unscrew the light bulbs too. Someone put tweezers in the light socket and it blew a fuse, now one side won’t turn on and when I turn on the lights they’re delayed. Can I fix this? [image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the vanity and switch...... oh, and throw away the tweezers.

Comment: The wiring probably burned open at the splice, they will need to be disassembled and repaired, two bad they were not standing in a bathtub.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so that you know how the site operates.

Comment: Jack, I posted the picture of the wiring on the side that is not working. The switch is all the way on the other side of the room.

Comment: Did the tweezer person get injured? More importantly, did they learn their lesson on sticking things into light sockets? On a more technical note, if the other side of the fixture still works fine, there is likely a damaged wire somewhere between them that is not making good contact. The fact that the fuse doesn't blow again would likely mean it is the Neutral wire (the white ones). look carefully at all of the connections to white wires for any carbon from arcing.

Comment: What I want to know is why in the world would someone put a pair of tweezers into a live light socket???      Ed Beal...it's attitudes like yours (bathtub), that is why we are all being forced into dual function breakers for everything!  .,..just kidding of course, I laughed when I read that. Thanks for the laugh, my sentiments exactly.

Comment: @EdBeal, a dry, acrylic bathtub would probably provide very good protection from electrocution

Comment: @jraf with an overload condition the weak link fails. It could be a white OR black the weakest connection will be the point of failure. Sorry if I offended anyone, I should have just answered but the term a little chlorine in the gene pool came to mind and that’s how it came out.

Answer (score 2):

OK... what you need to do is:

1) after turning off the power, remove the two screws above and below the middle socket of the vanity lights that are not working. Examine the wires in the junction box for any burn parks are disconnected wires. Redo any connections that look bad.

2) Remove the cover from the other side of the vanity, the side that's working, and examine the connections for the wires from other lights to where they hook up to the white and black wires from the switch. Look for burnt or disconnected wires. Redo any connections that look bad. Put a light bulb in each side and turn on the power and flip the switch and see what happens. Good luck.

Comment: To me it looks like the bottom is the start of the chain but it could be at the splice in the wall , black or white if either wire fails the lights will not light (comment above not correct) but I agree with looking for the splice on the other side also , there may be a box behind each fixture or just 1 but the wires on those fixtures are usually not very long so the splice in this one in the photo should be in a box.